# Math or MathUtils - Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm doing lots of trigonometry calculations in each frame. Are Java's Math functions faster than Libgdx's MathUtils?

Or is there any other library I can use that is faster than both of these?

Comment: Don't do premature optimization. Use any of them and only care about it when you realize that those calculations really are a bottleneck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trigonometric functions of `com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils` is faster than analogs in `java.lang.Math`. For example for `sin()` and `cos()` methods it returns nearest value from precalculated table. This is definitely less accurate than precise calculation but much faster:

```
static public float sin (float radians) {
    return Sin.table[(int)(radians * radToIndex) & SIN_MASK];
}
```

Other methods of `MathUtils` are mostly utility functions which are used by other parts of LibGDX. I think they are written mostly for convenience than for speed (but they are well optimized too).